# Jquery UI Draggable + Resizable Containment issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently trying to apply a containment to both the resize and the drag of a component. The drag accepts the containment bounds perfectly but the resize decides to break out and not follow the specified boundaries that I have set - anything i'm doing wrong here?

See the following jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/30/);

```
$(".Event3").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: "#2"
}).resizable({
    axis: "x",
    handles: "e, w",
    containment: "#2"
})
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to contain the resizable in an element that isn't its parent (`#2`)

Try setting the container to its parent `.TimelineContainer`:

```
$(".Event3").resizable({
    axis: "x",
    handles: "e, w",
    containment: ".TimelineContainer"
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/31/)

**Update:**

From the JQuery-UI documentation it appears that the intended use of the containment option is to be used within the confines of a parent element. It doesn't seem possible to use this option the way you intend. Try something like:

```
$(".Event3").resizable({
    axis: "x",
    handles: "e, w",
    containment: ".TimelineContainer",
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        // Define the dimensions of this element
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var width = ui.size.width;
        var right = left + width;
        // Define my constraints based on the element #2
        var constraintLeft = $('#2').position().left;
        var constraintWidth = $('#2').width();
        var constraintRight = constraintLeft + constraintWidth; 
        // if resizable has gone further left than the constraint
        if(left < constraintLeft) { 
            var left = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
            // measure the difference between this left and the constraint left
            var difference = constraintLeft - left;
            // make up the difference
            $(this).css('left', constraintLeft);      
            // make sure your width stays the same
            $(this).width($(this).width() - difference);
            // cancel the event
            $(this).resizable('widget').trigger('mouseup');
        }
        // if resizable has gone further right than the constraint
        if( right > constraintRight) {
            // change the width to fit between the constraint right and this left
            $(this).width(constraintRight - left);
            // cancel the event
            $(this).resizable('widget').trigger('mouseup');
        }
    }
});
```

Where you manually define the boundaries of the resizable and then you call a mouseup when the resizable has reached those boundaries. Here's the fiddle to play around with:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/35/)

Comment: I want to actually restrict the drag to the div #2 - as the drag does in its current form

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't restrain the drag to the bounds of the white div (#2) which is what I need

Comment: @user2616550 That's because I've manually defined the boundaries inside the resize event. The `constraintLeft` and `constraintRight` are designated based off the proportions of the element `#2`. I've added some comments to the code.

Comment: @user2616550 Here's a fiddle that more accurately resizes. Feel free to play around with the code! http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/35/ 
I've added some comments and added to the update. Good luck =D

Comment: That's a nice workaround given I can't house the div inside another to fake those boundaries with my current requirement - thanks!

Comment: @user2616550 Sure thing. Last thing to note is you don't have to cancel the the event after they exceed the boundaries if you don't want to. Just remove this line in its two locations: `$(this).resizable('widget').trigger('mouseup');` 
It will still function as expected.